# Как нарисовать сегмент в виде полукруга, или круг с вырезом(как пирог без кусочка)? Можно ли так сделать через апи?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Главное это отрисовать поверх Яндекс карты сегменты в виде полукруга и круга без одного сектора. Возможно ли это сделать с помощью апи или нужно как то создать слой над картой? Не догоняю как это сделать …
Через апи получается только полные фигуры, а многоугольник думаю не будет круглый. центр круга задается широтой и долготой

Comment: А сегменты вообще должны быть связаны с данными карты и координатами? Если это легенда, до лучше просто сделать её силами HTML и CSS. Примеры есть и здесь - https://stackoverflow.com/q/14184494/13744356 А было также рабочее решение вот тут, вроде: https://coding.likeflow.ru/2019/02/blog-post_635.html

Comment: Центр должен задаваться широтой и долготой

Comment: у вас открывается jfiddle во второй ссылке ?

Comment: Да, через анонимайзер фиддл ещё доступен и "пирог с кусочком" там отрисован.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ содержится здесь coding.likeflow.ru/2019/02/blog-post_635.html . Нужно перевести координаты в глобальные пиксели и нарисовать круг полигоном. YaCor первый нашел ответ, но не могу отметить комментарий правильным ответом.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]